# ORA-28001: The password has expired

Tags: oracle

I'm facing the problem about my database in Oracle, When I opened my database, it appear a message with: "ORA-28001: The password has expired"

I have updated my account with somes:

```
sqlplus /nolog
SQL> connect / as SYSDBA
Connected.

SQL> SELECT username, account_status FROM dba_users WHERE ACCOUNT_STATUS LIKE '%EXPIRED%';

SQL> ALTER USER system IDENTIFIED BY system;         
User altered.

SQL> ALTER USER system ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
User altered.

SQL> ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
Profile altered.

SQL> exit
```

I check and see that, my account: 'system' has OPEN, but I open it on Oracle SQL Developer, it still have alert:

```
ORA-28001: The password has expired
```

I have refered very much links but it still same the problem, how to fix this?

Comment: Does it prompt you to enter new password? or Go to SQL*PLUS and try to login it will prompt you to enter new password. OR right click on the the connection name and you will see `Reset Password` on context menu. Or use `alter user username identified by newpassword replace oldpassword`.

Comment: In SQL developer, Reset Password was disable, I use prompt: alter user username identified by newpassword replace oldpassword, however it's same error :(

Comment: It's seem I can not connected to db

Comment: Have you tried to use SQL*PLUS? Otherwise if the `Reset Password` is disabled then go to here.http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/11/resetting-your-oracle-user-password-with-sql-developer/

Comment: Is `system` your original password for `SYSTEM` user?

Comment: Yes, it is original password

Comment: Hey buddy your process is correct. You just forgot to "  commit;  " after profile altered.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I have fixed the problem, just need to check:

```
open_mode from v$database
```

and then check:

```
check account_status to get mode information
```

and then use:

```
alter user myuser identified by mynewpassword account unlock;
```

Comment: I only used  "alter user" and it worked. What are the first two statements for?

Comment: The first statement should be "select open_mode from v$database;" and the second one should be "select account_status from dba_users where username='myuser';".

Answer (score 73):

```
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
alter user EPUSR100 identified by EPUSR100 account unlock;
commit;
```

Answer (score 19):

Try to connect with the users in SQL Plus, whose password has expired. it will prompt for the new password. Enter the new password and confirm password.

It will work

[SQL Plus output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjfys.png)

Comment: Similar in Db Visualizer, there is a "Change password" connection property

Answer (score 15):

Check **"PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME"** by

Sql > `select * from dba_profiles;`

Set to Never expire

Sql> `ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;`

Then reset the password of locked user.

Comment: I have tried to reset with: alter user system identified by new_password account unlock; , but same error

Answer (score 13):

```
C:\>sqlplus /nolog
SQL> connect / as SYSDBA
SQL> select * from dba_profiles;
SQL> alter profile default limit password_life_time unlimited;
SQL> alter user database_name identified by new_password;
SQL> commit;
SQL> exit;
```

Comment: For system user; you need to re-set your password with: "alter user system identified by newpa$$word;"

Comment: How is this supposed to work when you can't login in the first place?

Answer (score 10):

- Connect to Oracle

**sqlplus sys/root as sysdba** [image: connected to oracle]

- Check the status and expiry date for the user

**SELECT username, account_status, expiry_date FROM dba_users;**

[image: status]

- Change the password for the user to resolve expiry

**ALTER USER dummy_user IDENTIFIED BY dummy_password;**

[image: change password]

- Unlock the user account if it locked

**ALTER USER dummy_user ACCOUNT UNLOCK;**

- Set the password expiry limit to unlimited to avoid issue in the future

**ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;**

[image: password unlimit]

- Again check the status of the user to verify the expiry date. The account status is now open and the expiry date is unlimited.

**SELECT username, account_status, expiry_date FROM dba_users;**

[image: status1]

SQL commands:

> sqlplus sys/root as sysdba

> SELECT username, account_status, expiry_date FROM dba_users;

> ALTER USER dummy_user IDENTIFIED BY dummy_password;

> ALTER USER dummy_user ACCOUNT UNLOCK;

> ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem even after changing the password, it wasn't getting reflected in SQLDEVELOPER.

Atlast following solved my problem :

1. Open Command Propmt
2. Type sqlplus
3. login as sysdba
4. Run following command :
       alter user USERNAME identified by NEW_PASSWORD;

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem, i am trying to login database it appear a message with: "ORA-28001: The password has expired" , I have fixed the problem simple steps

1.open command prompt
2.type sqlplus
3.It will ask Enter Password, you can give old password, it will show password has expired ORA-28001
4.It will ask new password and retype password
5.It will change with new password
6.Go to the sql database and try to connect with new password, it will connect.

Comment: For those who have this on Docker Desktop like me - in Containers list click on your container name, then Terminal tab, and all the same starting with step #2

Comment: And you can use the same password (at least for default settings of Oracle images)

Answer (score 4):

I am running Oracle 18c in a Docker container, where the problematic database is a Pluggable database, so I had to take a different approach:

1. Log in to SYSDBA
2. Switch to Pluggagle Database

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=XEPDB2;
   ```
3. Remove Password Expiry

   ```sql
   ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
   ```
4. Get Current User Details

   ```sql
   SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER','username') stmt from dual;
   ```

   Replace the `username` above with your own.

   The output will be something like:

   ```sql
   CREATE USER "…" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '…'
   ```
5. To reset the password, run as:

   ```sql
   ALTER USER "…" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES '…' ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
   ```

   … using the username and password from the previous step.

This is a combination of other answers here and elsewhere.

Comment: Sometimes get_ddl result will be truncated. To see the full value, you can call 'set long 100000' before calling get_ddl.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an additional error `ORA-65066: The specified changes must apply to all containers` you have to switch first to the root cdb:

```
alter session set container=CDB$ROOT;
```

and then the alter command should work:

```
alter user USER identified by NEW_PASSWORD account unlock;
```

Answer (score 0):

To know which users are expired, run command
SELECT * FROM <DATABASE USERS/PROFILES>;

To unlock users, run command
alter user  identified by  account unlock;

Answer (score -1):

Simple..
Goto Command prompt and type
SQLPLUS /@connect string
Hit Enter.

It says password expired and provide the option to enter new password.
Enter new password and you are done.

Comment: There are other answers (and a accepted one) that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer [see: How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score -3):

Just go to the machine where your database resides, search windows -> search SqlPlus
Type the user name, then type password, it will prompt you to give new password. On providing new password, it will say successfully changed the password.

Answer (score -4):

you are in wrong cdb/pdb so connect to right pdb