# Unable to create connection in oracle sql developer

Tags: oracle

Unable to create connection in oracle sql developer. Whenever i am trying to create a new connection for system user, getting user of "Password expired".

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, flagged to be removed. Also you can see what your problem is in the image you posted "Password has expired"

Comment: Please refer the How to Ask link stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Please include [actual details not an image](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), and show [how far your research took you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/), otherwise this could look to some like an ["it's not working" question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem, just need to check:

open_mode from v$database
and then check:

check account_status to get mode information
and then use:

alter user myuser identified by mynewpassword account unlock;

Thank you !

you will find this answer in this link :
[ORA-28001: The password has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40581131/ora-28001-the-password-has-expired)